# android firebase - displayname is not setting the display name. is this a bug?

Tags: android, web-services, firebase, firebase-authentication

It seems I can only find a way to update the display name of a current user, although I would like to do it while registering.

Here is the code I have been trying but it is not working, i have read about a bug in firebase that requires signing out for the display name to show but this hasnt solved my problem. Here is the code

```
    public void btnRegistrationUser_Click(View v) {
        final String email = txtEmailAddress.getText().toString();
        final String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        final String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegistrationActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Processing...", true);
        (firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password ))
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //Sign in the user here
                            signin(email,password,username);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signin(String email, String password, final String username) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //New Account is signed in and now the Current User
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "curr user is "+user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "passed in username is "+username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(username)
                                    .build();
//                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "curr display name is "+user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Intent i = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try to login the user since the account registration is successful. That way the current user would be the currently registered one.

```
      public void btnRegistrationUser_Click(View v) {
        final String email = txtEmailAddress.getText().toString();
        final String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        final String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegistrationActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Processing...", true);
        (firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password ))
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //Sign in the user here
                            signin(email,password,username);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signin(String email, String password, final String username) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //New Account is signed in and now the Current User
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "curr user is "+user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(username)
                                    .build();
                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                 @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "curr display name is "+user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                            Intent i = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

You also forgot the user by calling the updateProfile() method.
Check this out for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: if you mean my firebaseAuth It throws up an error - cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>

Comment: Sorry that should be firebaseAuth based on your variable

Comment: Try to make firebaseAuth final.

Comment: I just tried to edit your answer there to show you what I have done, although now it is toasting the correct email address but display name is still nul. I didnt get an error log previously it was just like a pop up error with the code underlined.

Comment: could this be a bug in firebase? when I toast the username variable it is fine but when i try use it to displayName, displayName always stays null

Comment: It is not throwing an error it is just not setting the display name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140139/discussion-between-kurt-acosta-and-mick-ogorman).